# Django - How to use sorl-thumbnail?

Tags: python, django, sorl-thumbnail

I'm using Django with PostgreSQL but I need to use some App to handle thumbnails. There is an app very well rated called [Sorl-Thumbnail](https://github.com/sorl/sorl-thumbnail)

In the installation instructions says that I need to use a [key value/caching system](http://sorl-thumbnail.readthedocs.org/en/latest/requirements.html#kvstore-requirements).

My doubt is: Can I use PostgreSQL database as cache or I will must to install memcached or redis?

I'm currently not using any caching mechanisms, the website is targeted for low traffic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You *can* use the [database cache backend](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/cache/?from=olddocs#database-caching), or even the [FS cache backend](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/cache/?from=olddocs#filesystem-caching). By "you can", I mean that "it will work". Just configure it normally for your django project and sorl-thumbnail will use it.

As per sorl-thumbnail documentation:

> a cached database which requires **no special installation to your normal Django setup besides installing a proper cache** *like memcached*

But it won't be as awesome as memcached or redis.

(Also: why does sorl-thumbnail require this now ? It used to just check the FS to ensure that the thumbnail exists or else create it)

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I've forgotten to syncdb.